# How do I get vim to highlight invalid fields, methods in my golang file

Tags: filetype-go

When I am using IntelliJ, if particular method is not present in the library version of my package, I see errors like these.

The red color code is error. `Interface` is not present in the in my `current` object.

[image]

- When I open the same file in vim, I do not get similar feedback.

---

Here is a simpler version of the problem in another file.

- go build fails to build the package.

```
go build  -buildmode=pie -ldflags '-s -w -X pkg/version/info.Version=v1.6.4-rc1-379-g7748fdb0-dirty -X pkg/awsutils/awssession.version=v1.6.4-rc1-379-g7748fdb0-dirty' -o aws-cni           ./cmd/routed-eni-cni-plugin
# github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/cmd/routed-eni-cni-plugin
cmd/routed-eni-cni-plugin/cni.go:268:4: unknown field 'Version' in struct literal of type types100.IPConfig
```

But when I open the file in vim, I see no highlight.

[image]

I am also using vim-go plugin, with all the binaries installed including gopls

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Using a tagged release; wildcard allowed (requires git 1.9.2 or above)
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

let g:go_highlight_types = 1
let g:go_highlight_fields = 1
let g:go_highlight_functions = 1
let g:go_highlight_function_calls = 1
let g:go_highlight_extra_types = 1
let g:go_highlight_operators = 1
~
```

Essentially, I want syntax highlight-lighting that points wrong methods or api signatures based on the library version in `go.mod`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Re: `I see errors like this`: I'm probably missing something, but I don't really see an error in your screenshot? As for the more general question, vim-go includes things like autocompletion and error reporting, but you can also use a generic LSP plugin (such as ALE, vim-lsc, coc, many others) which uses `gopls`; I'm not sure how module versions are really relevant as such, because all tools use the current version specified in your go.mod (but maybe IntelliJ does something special with it? I'm not familiar with that).

Comment: Since @MartinTournoij didn't mention it, there's also his own Gopher plugin, though IIUC it doesn't _automatically_ show such errors (but rather relies on the standard `:compiler`/`:make` system).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please note that requests for plugins are off-topic here. Instead, consider [edit]ing your question around the frame "How do I accomplish X?" to which the answer might be "use these plugins."

Comment: Martin and Ben : Thank you. I have explained the problem a little better. Please take a look and see if I am missing something.